# Mac OS arrow keys not working properly when enabling paredit in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, arrow-keys

I currently have this in my .emacs, which worked just fine in Linux:

```
;; paredit                                                                       
;; this is from somewhere else on Stackoverflow                                  
;; deals with curly brackets matching and stuff                                  
;; I edited the answer a little bit                                              

(defmacro setup-paredit (func-name mode-map)                                     
  `(defun ,func-name ()                                                          
     (define-key ,mode-map                                                       
       (kbd "DEL") 'paredit-backward-delete)                                     
     (define-key ,mode-map                                                       
       (kbd "{") 'paredit-open-curly)                                            
     (define-key ,mode-map                                                       
       (kbd "}") 'paredit-close-curly)                                           
     (modify-syntax-entry ?\{ "(}")                                              
     (modify-syntax-entry ?\} "){")                                              
     (modify-syntax-entry ?\[ "(]")                                              
     (modify-syntax-entry ?\] ")[")                                              
     (modify-syntax-entry ?~ "'   ")                                             
     (modify-syntax-entry ?, "    ")                                             
     (modify-syntax-entry ?^ "'")                                                
     (modify-syntax-entry ?= "'")))                                              

(defmacro setup-paredit-mode (func-name mode-map mode-hook)                      
  `(progn (setup-paredit ,func-name ,mode-map)                                   
          (add-hook ',mode-hook ',func-name)                                     
          (add-hook ',mode-hook 'enable-paredit-mode)))                          

;; probably doing lots of things wrong but at least this seems to work well      
(setup-paredit-mode setup-c++-paredit c++-mode-map c++-mode-hook)               
(setup-paredit-mode setup-slime-repl-paredit slime-repl-mode-map slime-repl-mod\
e-hook)                                                                          
(setup-paredit-mode setup-slime-paredit slime-mode-map slime-mode-hook)         
(setup-paredit-mode setup-clojure-paredit clojure-mode-map clojure-mode-hook)   
(setup-paredit-mode setup-emacs-paredit emacs-lisp-mode-map emacs-lisp-mode-hoo\
k)                                                                               
(setup-paredit-mode setup-css-paredit css-mode-map css-mode-hook)
```

But the last bit in Mac OS X makes arrow keys produce the following output:

```
[C [A [D [A [B [D [C [B [D [B [D]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Another weird thing when hitting `C-x C-c`:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: switch-to-buffer-in-tab
```

I finally killed it with `C-x C-z`.

These do not happen if I comment out the last part after `;; probably...`, so the problem probably lies there. How should I go about fixing this problem?

**EDIT**:

I found [this](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/ist/How+to+get+the+Arrow+keys+to+work+in+Emacs). Simply copy-pasting the code there didn't work. Hitting the arrow keys gave me this:

```
# ESC [ ⇧A ESC [ ⇧B ESC [ ⇧C ESC [ ⇧D #
```

Being the newb I am, I am not sure how to "adjust the code given above appropriately," though. (Also what is that up arrow doing?)

**EDIT 2**:

The `C-c C-x` problem, at least, seems to have been solved somehow with this .emacs code:

```
;; Fix Mac arrow keys                                                            
(if (not window-system);; Only use in tty-sessions.                              
     (progn                                                                      
      (defvar arrow-keys-map (make-sparse-keymap) "Keymap for arrow keys")       
      (define-key esc-map "[" arrow-keys-map)                                    
      (define-key arrow-keys-map "⇧A" 'previous-line)                            
      (define-key arrow-keys-map "⇧B" 'next-line)                                
      (define-key arrow-keys-map "⇧C" 'forward-char)                             
      (define-key arrow-keys-map "⇧D" 'backward-char)))
```

Arrow keys still not working when paredit is active.

**EDIT 3**:

I should add that all this is happening inside the Terminal. I am not sure whether it still happens with the GUI, because somehow my .emacs is causing Aquamacs to not display any windows.

Arrow keys work fine in Emacs GUI, but not in `-nw` mode.

Comment: Aquamacs adds a lot of strange customizations to Emacs which may be messing with your .emacs. I'd suggest you try the Emacs Mac port instead (https://github.com/downloads/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port/Emacs.zip) — it is more likely to behave like both Emacs and a Mac app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. In Terminal Preferences, under Settings > Advanced > Emulation, I set `Declare terminal as:` to `vt100`.

I did try this before, but it turns out that **you need to close the Terminal window** before starting Emacs up again, otherwise it will still use the current settings.

Now the downside is that Emacs is B&W. Will see if any other emulation settings work.

**EDIT**:

`xterm-256color` (the default) works just fine, with color. GRRRRR. All this because some tutorial (I forgot for what) told me to set the Terminal emulation to `rxvt`. Hahahaha.

At least I hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: Yes, the terminal type is only read at startup. Really you should not need to remap the arrow keys though, something more basic must be wrong.

Comment: @NicholasRiley Thanks! It turns out I didn't need to remap arrow keys after all, just needed to set the terminal type correctly :)

Comment: Glad you got it to work! It's pretty depressing we're still struggling with terminal types in 2012, but such is the price of backward compatibility...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and i assume you will be able to resolve the same
chsh -s /bin/bash

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.